# Can I search male/female keywords in "indexOf" jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to search these keyword ('male', 'female') using `indexOf()` but it's not working.
In case I'm finding 'male', it's searching both string male and female.

Is this a correct way?

```
if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(a.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
     $(this).show();
}
```

Comment: Note that `female` does contain `male`. It might explain your problem.

Comment: i have two dropdown male and female. if i'm selecting male dropdown, it's showing both male and female..

Answer (score 1):

Try a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) with [word boundaries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary)

```
var regex = new RegExp('\b' + a + '\b', i)
if (regex.test($(this).text())) {
    $(this).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regexp to find only words (`\b` - word boundary):

```
var str = 'There is one male and one female in this test';

if (str.match(/\bmale\b/i)) {
  console.log('Found male!');
} else {
  console.log('No male here!');
}


var str2 = 'There is one female and another female in this test';

if (str2.match(/\bmale\b/i)) {
  console.log('Found male!');
} else {
  console.log('No male here!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `text="female"` then yes it contatins the words female and male, so the search for male would not be unambiguous. Maybe in the whole string there is something that allways surrounds the substring male or female. For example `text="sex=female`". If that would be the case then you could add the extra bit to your search pattern.